# Anaconda navigator not launching windows 10 (Spyder as well)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I installed the anaconda 64 bit on windows 10. I can launch the prompt but when I try to open navigator thru the icon or thru prompt, I'm getting the error below. Can someone help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 103, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 34, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 37, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.analytics import GATracker
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\analytics.py", line 44, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.external.UniversalAnalytics import Tracker
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\external\UniversalAnalytics\Tracker.py", line 28, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import (HTTPSHandler, Request, build_opener,
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'six.moves.urllib.request' (unknown location)
```

Also, Spyder is also not launching. I can launch Jupyter and prompt.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to install the Anaconda (Python 3.7 version) on Windows 10 and I was facing the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\***>anaconda-navigator Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())   File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 103, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app   File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 34, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow   File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 39, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.analytics import GATracker   File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\analytics.py", line 44, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.external.UniversalAnalytics import Tracker   File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\external\UniversalAnalytics\Tracker.py", line 28, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import (HTTPSHandler, Request, build_opener, ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'six.moves.urllib.request' (unknown location)
```

I did the solution explained [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273) and it worked.

Comment: I found the exact same problem after installing anaconda3 and trying to open Anaconda Navigator, the solution described in that link also worked!

Answer (score 2):

Error printed is related to ssl library and its natural for people to go and try reinstalling openssl library. But to fix this below steps have to be followed. Just now tried and confirmed this is working.

Copy the following files:

libcrypto-1_1-x64.* (.dll and .pdb files)
libssl-1_1-x64.* (.dll and .pdb files)

From D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin to D:\Anaconda3\DLLs.

Same issue is described in anacondas github [page](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273).

Answer (score 1):

For me it works after installing "Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1d Light"