# Anaconda Navigator does not open (Windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda3

I just downloaded and installed Anaconda3 on windows 10 platform.

[image]

Apparently, the installation process finished successfully however I can't open Anaconda Navigator.

What I'm doing is just clicking on "Anaconda Navigator" icon from start menu.

[image]

After a while an empty console window pops up twice, then it desappears immediately without showing an error message and nothing seems to happen after that.

[image]

I've been reading about similar errors and found out that running this command, `conda update --all` might solve the problem.

[image]

I tried it out, but ended up getting a network connection problem for a particular URL.

[image]

But my internet connection is working fine since I'm actually able to access that URL from the browser and get a response.

[image]

It's worth mentioning that I've already uninstall Anaconda3 and set up the following user environment variables.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to this problem, I recommend you to read the official documentation and follow the steps described there in order to make sure everything was installed correctly.

Check out this article: 
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/verify-install/

After trying to starting up Anaconda Navigator from the console I got this specific error that helped me to get a final solution.

[image]

Basically I just had to move some files within anaconda3 installation folder from one path to another.

Navigate to `%ANACONDA_HOME%\Library\bin`, there you will find the files listed below

- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
- libcrypto-1_1-x64.pdb
- libssl-1_1-x64.dll
- libssl-1_1-x64.pdb

So, just move them to this path: `%ANACONDA_HOME%\DLLs`

Give it a try one more time and you will be able to run it.

[image]

**Note:**
***%ANACONDA_HOME%*** refers to Anaconda3 installation folder in your computer.

This answer is based on this link: [Anaconda navigator not launching windows 10 (Spyder as well)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878142/anaconda-navigator-not-launching-windows-10-spyder-as-well)